# OctoberCMS Validation issue for required but dependent field with asterisk

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller

I am using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) and I have used [Builder](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder) plugin to create one of my plugins called as **Properties** which works fine so far.

The Thing is, I have 2 fields called as `authority` and `auction_date`.

`authority` is a drop-down field which has options like **auction** and etc.. whereas `auction_date` is simple a `date` field.

`auction_date` field depends on `authority` field and it is required only if `authority` field has a selected value called as **auction** and `authority` field is not required at the same time. Hence I put below code in my Property plugin's model file.

Model File - **Property.php**

```
public $rules = [
        'auction_date' => 'required_if:authority,==,auction',
    ];
```

This works well, I am able to validate my `auction_date` field if `authority` drop-down's value selected **auction** from the list.

However, here basically `auction_date` is not a required field by default. It is dependent field of `authority`.

Yet the field showing **asterisk(*)** beside this field when I load the page. Here below how it looks like.

[image]

I have tried to update my plugin's **fields.yaml** file my putting below code.

```
auction_date:
            label: 'Auction Date:'
            oc.commentPosition: ''
            mode: date
            span: auto
            type: datepicker
            tab: 'Address Information'
            required: false
```

This code `required: false` did not work for me.

I came across the solution to update below system library files.

- modules/backend/classes/FormField.php
- modules/backend/widgets/Form.php

And doing this, [Field definition should override magic](https://github.com/octobercms/october/commit/cd76f2e04fa527f156e687834c357be32ee8bf33).

But frankly, I do not want to mess with any system file here. It would be ideal if I can find some solution which can deal this thing inside one of plugin files.

If someone guide me to accomplish this, it would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wait for the next release or override the method used to determine if something is required.

```
public function filterFields($fields)
{
    $fields->auction_date->required = false;
}
```

Comment: It works. This helped me.  Thank you Mr. Co-Founder of OctoberCMS :)